# Direct access after authentication insteed iframe access

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-authentication

When the user authorize my app, he is redirected to my site and not to facebook with my app in the iframe. Is there a way to stay in facebook ?
My code :

```
require './src/facebook.php';

$config = array();
$config['appId'] = 'XXXXX';
$config['secret'] = 'XXXXX';
$config['fileUpload'] = false; // optional

$facebook = new Facebook($config);

$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}

// Login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.
if ($user) {
    echo "blah";
} else {
  $params = array(
      'scope' => 'read_stream, friends_likes',
      'redirect_uri' => 'https://xxxxx'
    );

  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
  echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $loginUrl . "'</script>");
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your app's url (http://apps.facebook.com/your_app_namespace) in the redirect_uri param. This should fix the issue you are facing.